# Headless Chrome Puppeteer select option from drop down without id

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, headless, puppeteer

I'm using headless chrome with nodejs puppeteer library mostly. I'm having trouble selecting or clicking any options in a drop down. The problem is all the IDs are dynamic and change with every click. I've tried scraping the HTML and searching for the current id, but to no avail.

Is there another way to select an option? Is it possible to use a different selector besides id?

[image: The code for the drop down]

note for image: where it says 'homeState-aria-id-7' the number 7 is dynamically generated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I am completely following the reason that having a dynamically created ID would cause issues. Here is an example with how I have solved the problem and using a selector for your code above.

```
page.evaluate(optionSelector => {
    return document.querySelector(optionSelector).setAttribute('selected, 'true');
}, 'select[name="homeState"] > option[value="AL"]');
```